# Is there a way to list all the default normal, visual and insert mode bindings in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

When you use the :map command without any parameters, it seems that it only lists custom and plugin bindings.  Is there a way to view ALL bindings?  It would be nice to know if a custom binding would conflict with one of the defaults.

Alternatively, is there a decent online reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a list of all of the standard key bindings that you can get by typing `:help index`.  Those are in addition to the custom ones printed out by `:map`.

Comment: Ah, that seems rather obvious now.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you would like to be sure not to interfere with any other plugin, take an available mapping beginning with `<leader>` which defaults to a backslash. `:map` will list mappings beginning with this leader key.

Comment: In addition to `:help index`, it may be quicker to check out `:help map-which-keys` which gives you general rules you can follow.