# Emacs Describe Key in vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

Is there any feature in Vim which shows me what a keyboard shortcut is bound to in the current context? Something like describe-key in emacs.

I'm trying to find out which keys i can safely rebind and which are bound to something useful.

Comment: There is some information here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778715/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-the-default-normal-visual-and-insert-mode-bindings-in

Comment: Cool thank you. That is very near at what I wanted to do. How do I efficiently search and group this output? --> jep there is see the solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your key is **manually** mapped, you can check the mapping by evoking:

```
:map <keys>
```

if it is not, then you can check the manual:

```
:help <keys>
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I wanted. :-) Just Great.

Comment: It's often helpful to use `:verb map <keys>` so you can find out where the mapping was set.

Answer (score 5):

The first google hit [says](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg12272.html):

*is there anything like "describe-key" (EMacs) in vim ?*

> The simplest might be the Vim help system.  For example:

`:h ^X`

> describes Ctrl-X.  You have to type "^X" as two characters, not one.

To see how a key is *mapped*, you can use `:map <whatever key sequence>`, or just `:map` to see all non-default bindings. Mappings of keys may contain non-trivial sequences, so you might need to look up several other keys used in the mapping with `:h` as said above.

Comment: btw, you can type special characters by first typing CTRL+V. For example, typing  CTR+V,<ENTER> gives you ^M.

Comment: Updated the answer to include mapping.